# About non-examples of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was thinking that question and I know that it's a very fool question but I couldn't convince myself. By definition $R$ is a ring with two operation addition and multiplication $+,.$

I know that $S_n , n\ge3$ is a non abelian group group under the composition $\circ$. I believe that we can't talk about ring structure on it as addition and multiplication is not defined on it. So, automatically it is not a ring.

Exactly the same reason valid for $D_n$, so it is not a ring. For example, select $n=3$ then what is $r+s$? Usual addition is not defined on $D_3$ so we can't talk about ring structure on it.

Is that a reason why they are **not ring**?

Comment: Well, you didn’t really show they can’t be made rings with the proper addition. You have just stated that, considered only as a group, they aren’t rings, which is trivially true.

Comment: Okay, it is clear that you can't define addition on symmetric group because of the non existence of identity element. However, how can we define addition on dihedral group? Also, we just vaguely say that it is group containing symmetries and reflections of regular n-gon. What was the operation on it?

Comment: It's a little strange to say that a structure that hasn't yet been equipped with ring operations $+, -, \cdot$ "is" or "is not" a ring, since there may be multiple ways of introducing ring operations that work. In other words, "[being] a ring" is not a mere property for which we can say whether or not the property holds: it's an extra structure. So the proper question might be: given an abelian group $A$, is there a ring structure for which the underlying additive group is $A$? This can be interesting. For example, there is no way for $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ to be the additive group of a ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ring is a set $A$ together with two binary operations, usually (but not necessarily) denoted $+$ and $\cdot$, satisfying certain properties (which I won't list).

The group $(S_3,\circ)$ is not a ring, because it is not a set together with two operations. Just like a cow is not a ring, because it is not a set together with two operations. It doesn't even get in the door.

Usually, when we ask if something is or is not a ring, the "something" has to be (1) a set; and (2) two operations on the set. Then we can check whether that set and those two operations satisfy the required properties.

If it is not a set, then it's not a ring, because it doesn't even qualify for the *possibility* of being a ring. If you are not given a set and *two* binary operations on it, with a specification of which one will play the role of $+$ and which one will play the role of $\cdot$, then you don't have a ring, again because it doesn't even qualify for the possibility of being a ring.

Only after you have been given a set and two binary operations does it make sense to start asking "does this operation have an identity? Does it have inverses? Is it associative?" etc. Not that you can't ask them beforehand, but rather that *there is no point* in asking them if you don't have a set with two binary operations.

Note that it's not about what the operations are called.

Now, one can ask: is there a binary operation $+$ we can define on $S_3$ so that $(S_3,+,\circ)$ will be a ring? Is there a binary operation $+$ we can define on $D_n$ so that $(D_n,+,\cdot)$ (where $\cdot$ is the usual group operation) that will make it into a ring? The answers in that case are "no", because in a ring, the multiplicative structure has an "absorbing element": an element $x$ such that $x\cdot y=y\cdot x = x$ for all $y$: namely, the identity of the *other* operation $+$. This means that if $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a ring, and $R$ has more than one element, then $(R,\cdot)$ is never a group.

(You could also ask: is there an operation $\odot$ such that $(S_3,\circ,\odot)$ is a ring, with $\circ$ playing the role of "addition"? Again, the answer is "no" because in a ring we require the addition operation to be commutative. You could ask: given an abelian group $(A,+)$, is there always an operation $\cdot$  such that $(A,+,\cdot)$ is a ring? That is a harder question if you always require your rings to have a unity, an easy one if you do not; in the latter case, just define $a\cdot b = 0$ for all $a,b\in A$, where $0$ is the identity of the group structure $(A,+)$.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I got everything well, but I have a question about the second of last paragraph. For example, I know that $(S_3,\circ)$ is group and I want to add one more operation on it which is $+$. You imply being ring fails because of the 'absorbing element'. What it is the absorbing element of $S_3$? We don't have multiplicative structure on it. Also I don't understand this part $(R,+,\cdot)$  is a ring, and R has more than one element, then $(R,\cdot)$ is never a group.

Comment: @FuatRay In order for $(S_3,+,\circ)$ to be a ring there would need to be an element $x$ in $S_3$ such that $x\circ  \sigma=x$ for all $\sigma$. There **is no such element**. That's why you cannot turn the group structure of $S_3$ into the multiplicative structure of a ring. Asking me what is the absorbing element means you completely **mis**understood what I'm saying, so you did not, in fact, "got  everything well". You missed the whole point. **Groups don't have absorbing elements**. They never do. The multiplicative structure of a ring **always has absorbing elements**.

Comment: So can I say that no matter what we have two operations (not necessarily addition $+$ and multiplication $\cdot$), the identity element of the group structure will be absorbing element of second operation. So, in our case it fails as it does not have absorbing element with respect to $\circ$.

Comment: @FuatRay if it is "not necessarily $+$ and $\cdot$", are you even talking about a ring at all? I have no idea. **In a ring**, the identity of the additive structure is always an absorbing element of the multiplicative structure. Here "additive" just means "whatever operation you are using to correspond to $+$ in the definition of a ring", and "multiplicative" means "whatever operation you are using to correspond to $\cdot$ in the definition of a ring".

Comment: What I mean is that for example set of square matrices are ring wrt $+$ and multiplication, of course rather than their usual. In our example, instead of multiplication we have composition. And I thought, our aim is we want to find one operation on $S_3$ satisfying group axioms which is impossible.

Comment: @FuatRay Again. What the operations *are* doesn't matter. One will play the role of $+$, one will play the role of $\cdot$. "finding one operation on $S_3$ satisfying the group axioms", without specifying anything else, is not "impossible": $S_3$ is **already** a group. If you mean, "can we find an operation on $S_3$ that will play the role of $+$, while the usual composition in $S_3$ plays the role of $\cdot$, so that we get a ring that way?" then you need to say so, all of it, and the answer is "no".

Comment: I know I look like an idiot but I really want to get the essence of the idea. If we take the operation $\circ$ plays the role of addition $+$ then our structure does not become a ring because it is not commutative. On the other hand, if $\circ$ plays the role of multiplicative $\cdot$ then our structure again is not a ring as it doesn't have absorbing elements.

Comment: @FuatRay correct. No ring has a multiplicative structure which is a group.

Answer (score 0):

The group $D_n$ can never be the underlying multiplicative monoid of a ring structure. In fact, no group can be the underlying multiplicative monoid of a ring structure. The reason is that every element in a group has an inverse, but the zero element of a ring cannot have a (multiplicative) inverse.

Comment: (Replace the word "monoid" by "semigroup" if your convention is that rings need not have a multiplicative identity. My convention is that they do (and I call a structure that doesn't a "rng").

Comment: According to my textbook, there is no requirement for being ring that every element has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Of course not! I just observed that 0 has no multiplicative inverse, and that's why $D_n$, or for that matter any other group, cannot be the multiplicative part of a ring, which is what I thought you might have been asking.

Comment: What do you mean by $\circ$ has no multiplicative inverse. Okay, for $S_3$ the first operation is composition so we have clearly inverses. How do you define multiplication on $S_3$? Like $f(x).g(x)$? So, $g(x)$ has to be $0$ which doesn't lie on $S_3$. Did I understand what you said?

Comment: No, I wrote O, meaning $0$ (I sometimes don't bother with LaTeX in comments), not $\circ$. As for the other questions, it sounds like there are some basic confusions to sort out. I decline to sort them out in a series of comment boxes, but if you want to open up a chat room, I can try to help out (may be later in the day, though -- I'm on North American Eastern time).

Answer (score 0):

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite group that is not abelian. The question is: can I define an operation $+\colon G\times G\to G$ such that $(G,+,\cdot)$ is a ring?
Suppose you can do it and call $R$ this "ringification" of your starting group $G$. Since $(G,\cdot)$ is a group every non-identity element admit an inverse, so $(R,+,\cdot)$ is not just a ring but what is called a division ring (or skew-field). Since every finite division ring is a field, you have that the operation $\cdot$ is commutative and it's false since $G$ is not abelian. So you cannot turn into a ring (in the sense of above) any finite non abelian group.

This should provide an answer for $S_n$ and $D_n$ with $n\geq3$, since they are finite non abelian groups.

Comment: Before your construction, it is not commutative so automatically first condition of being ring fails.

Comment: In a ring it's needed just the commutativity of the addition map. Anyway other answers pointed out a more general and easy argument.